# NMAP: Check if port 80 and 8080 is open

Tags: nmap

In our company, I want to check if users are running web servers on port 80 and 8080.

I downloaded nmap and ran this command:

```
nmap -p 80,8080 192.168.1.0-255
```

I got a list of IPs and tried to access them in my browser (EG: 192.168.1.1:8080) but wasn't able to connect.

Is my nmap command correct?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's the response:

```
Host is up (0.050s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Comment: Can you post you NMAP output. It may be detecting a web server on those ports but the server may not be serving a page.

Comment: // , Just because a port is open doesn't mean anything is using it.

Answer (score 67):

**Your NMAP command is fine. It's the service you're trying to connect to that is the "problem".**

You can find that a "server" has an open port on 80 or 8080 but still not be able to connect it.  For instance, I have about three dozen polycom phones that are accessible at port 8080 but they have bum config files.  When someone tries to access them at that port they aren't able to connect.

And it may depend on *how* you're trying to connect.  Even though its port 8080 maybe you aren't supposed to use a browser to connect to it.(I know - crazy idea).

Find out what type of device you're trying to connect to using this (you'll need sudo or root):

```
nmap -sS -O -p80,8080 192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: How do I use this to check port **22**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `-p22`

Comment: only the opened     `nmap -sS -O -p80,8080 192.168.1.0/24 | grep "tcp open" -B 4`

Comment: If you only want to see the IP addresses of servers that respond to the ports, you can use: `nmap -n -Pn 192.168.1.0/24 -p80,8080 -oG - | grep '/open/' | awk '/Host:/{print $2}'` (assumes all hosts are online).